# Updating to PHP 5.4 on Debian 6.0.5

Tags: linux, php, debian

Figured there would be an easy answer on Google, but no luck. Most of the tutorials, while similar to what I need, don't work on Debian:

http://chemicaloliver.net/internet/installing-php-5-4-in-ubuntu/

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

yields:

```
-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

And the steps here: http://vjetnamnet.com/how-to-install-php-5-4-on-debian-using-dotdeb-repository/  get to

```
apt-get update
N: Ignoring file 'dotdeb.gpg' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension 
N: Ignoring file 'dotdeb.gpg.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension 
E: Type 'Deb' is not known on line 1 in sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dotdeb.gpg` files shouldn't be in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  If you ran the `cat dotdeb.gpg | sudo apt-key add -` command, then you're finished with those files so you can delete them.

As for `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list`, `deb` has to be in all lower case.  You have a capital `D`.

Ubuntu is based on Debian, but isn't the same as Debian.  Instructions for Debian usually work in Ubuntu, but usually not the other way around.

Comment: Strange, that Deb was there by default from the turnkey solution I used.  But your recommended changes worked like a charm, thank you!